# Removing xml elements using php from a file having multiple named elements

Tags: php, xml, parsing

hi
i am working with a xml file and structure of the file is like

```
<ListRecords>
    <record>
</record>

<totalupnow> </totalupnow>

<record>
</record>
<record>
</record>
<record>
</record>
<record>
</record>
<totalupnow> </totalupnow>

</listrecord>
```

now i need a php program tht just removes the `<totalupnow> </totalupnow>` from this file.. the file is very big in size almost 4 gbs.

please help me out...

or if there is anyway i can only read the `<record> </record>` from this leaving the `<totalupnow> </totalupnow>` as it is.

Comment: You probably don't want to use PHP for this. PHP usually tries to load a whole file into memory which is obviously a bad idea. You can use a workaround by duplicating the file line-by-line with fgets and write, but it would be cumbersome.

A better way would be to use a programming language/shell script/tool that is better suited for your goal, e.g. sed.

Comment: What is in the `<record>` elements? Character data? More elements?

Comment: @dtech: You are not really recommending regex to parse XML here, are you? PHP is suited well to do this via SAX...

Comment: i am using php xml dom parser.. it works fine but when it reaches to <totalupnow> after record it stops...and one thing more it also stops when the file is large. please help me out i am just stucked with this file for a long time :(

Comment: @Tomalak did I say anything about regex in my post? But I did not know of SAX

Comment: @dtech: You recommended `sed`.

Comment: @Tomalak it would work to remove only 1 single tag (and all its contents) from a large file.

Comment: @dtech: No. Nested tags of the same name would be enough break this, and so would an unfortunate comment with the tag in it. Parsers exist for XML, and if you have to process a 4GB file I think it's time to use them. It's not that it would be *hard* to use them, so resorting to regex is doubly stupid.

Comment: @Tomalak nested tags and comments wouldn't break it. Simply using sed 's/<tagname>.*</tagname>//' file would work if the tag is on a single line (as in the example). Multiline and embedded tags are more difficult but not impossible, comments probably are. But of course it's not the correct tool if you want to handle every xml file instead of xml files with those specific constraints.

Comment: @dtech: `sed s/<tagname>.*</tagname>//` breaks for two tags on a single line. And for `<tagname><![CDATA[ </tagname> ]]></tagname>`. For every regex you come up with I can find something that breaks it, and in less time than you needed for the regex. Just give it up, regex is not a tool that can successfully parse/modify XML in any broader sense than a quick and dirty one-off hack in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [event-based streaming XML parser (SAX)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) to parse such a file. It works a little differently than a DOM parser, but in exchange it can work with files of any size.

> [...] or if there is anyway i can only read the `<record> </record>`

To keep things simple, I assume your `<record>` elements contain nothing but text and that "read" means "write their contents to the screen".

```
<?php 
$file       = "your_big_file.xml"; 
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 

// set up some basic parser properties
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); 
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 

// set up your event handlers    
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement"); 
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents"); 

// read the file in 4kb chunks and parse these as they are read
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) { 
  if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) { 
    die( sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d", 
         xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)), 
         xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser))); 
  } 
} 

// clean up
xml_parser_free($xml_parser); 

// EVENT HANDLERS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$in_record = false;
$counter   = 0;
$depth     = 0;

// this function is called whenever a start element (<foo>) is encountered
function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs) { 
  global $in_record; 
  global $depth; 
  global $counter;

  $depth++; 
  $in_record = ($name == "record");

  if ($in_record) {
    $counter++;
    echo "Record #$counter:\n"; 
  }
} 

// this function is called whenever a start element (</foo>) is encountered
function endElement($parser, $name) { 
  global $in_record; 
  global $depth; 

  $depth--; 
  $in_record = ($name != "record");
} 

// this function is called whenever text data is encountered
function contents($parser, $data) { 
  global $in_record; 

  if ($in_record) {
    echo "\t".$data."\n"; 
  }
} 

?>
```

Comment: @Muhammad I don't understand that comment. Also, have you actually *tried* using my suggestion? Because what I *won't* to is solve your entire problem for you.

Comment: actually i think if i send u the file, so that u can understand the format of the file exactly. please as i am just tired. working with this almost for a month but no gain. please help me out.

Comment: @Muhammad Send me the file? Sorry, but no. My example is pretty straight-forward, your question is rather vague, and I don't feel like doing *all* your work for you.

Comment: i am trying that example but i think u hv sent tht wihout knowing the exact format of the file. as u hv asked earlier about <record> element. thts wht i am asking u to understand the format of the file and then guide me. i am nt asking u to do all my work dear. i can understand it. so please!

Comment: @Muhammad I don't know the exact format of your input because you did for some reason not provide it in your question. Tip for the next time: If you want a specific answer to a specific problem, ask a specific question. Sorry if that sounds harsh, but the time you invest now in trying to convince me to go back to the drawing board for you would have been better spent in asking exactly what you wanted to know right from the start.